# in the svn ant task, is there a way to checkout from svn without hard coding the credentials?

Tags: svnant

i'm trying to checkout a code base from an svn URL. It works fine  when i hard code the credentials or define it as a property. My question is, is it possible to get the credentials from the user at runtime (i.e. when I run the build.xml script) ?

```
<target name="svn">
    <svn **username="the username here" password="the password here"**>
        <checkout url="the url" destPath="${checkout}" />
    </svn>
</target>
```

thanks in advance.. :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the input task of Ant beforehand, as in:

```
   <input message="Please enter username:" addproperty="user" />
```

Then just use `${user}` for the **svn username** property.